# Git behaviour when merging

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I have a project with a source branch - Branch1 and two branches which I have sourced from Branch1, say Branch2 and Branch3.

I delete a file in Branch2 and ask it to be merged to Branch1. It gets successfully merged.

I do an update to a file in Branch3 but the file deleted in Branch2 is still seen in Branch3.

Then I get it successfully merged to Branch1.

But I thought Git will merge a snapshot of Branch3 which still has the file on to Branch1. 
But alas No, the file deleted in the first merge request is gone.
In fact during the merge request of Branch3 to Branch1, git doesn't even tell me that file as  diff in GitLab.

My question is, I thought Git will always copy the whole snapshot of Branch3 and merge it to Branch1.

Why didn't that happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think I understand your question from your verbal description. However, you can make it more clear by using specific file names (even if they are made up). In particular, I'm unclear whether "I delete a file in Branch2" and "I do an update to a file in Branch3" refer to different files or the same file. Using names for these two files will make it much more clear what you mean.

Comment: Even better, show _actual_ git commands throughout.

Comment: @matt Yes, that, too.

Comment: Especially because the phrase "do an update to a file in Branch3" is totally meaningless. Do you mean you pulled? edited? what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this more concrete, let's call the file you deleted on Branch 2 `foo.txt`. When you merge Branch 2 into Branch 1, this file is now deleted on Branch 1 as well. Since Branch 3 does not modify this file, it remains deleted on Branch 1 even after you merge Branch 3.

The best way to think about this is that merging copies the **changes** from one branch to another. It does not copy an entire snapshot when you merge. This is still a little hand-wavy, though. To get a more accurate mental model of how git works, it is important to understand what a commit is. Basically a commit is a set of changes as well as some additional meta data, such as a timestamp, author's name, etc. [This article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html) gives an in-depth description that is very helpful.

A branch then is a sequence of commits. When you checkout a branch, git creates local copies of all the files it tracks by applying all of the changes in the commits on that branch. The same goes for merging: `git merge branch1` will apply all of the changes which are in branch1 but not in the current branch to the local files.

Now it is easier to understand what happens in the following commands:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch3
```

Since Branch 3 does not change the file which was deleted on Branch 1, git leaves it as it is. Git will only apply the changes from Branch 3 which are not already part of Branch 1.

Comment: In many ways it doesn't matter, but I think it's better not to claim that a commit is a *change*. It's actually a *snapshot*. The way in which this matters is more important here, because when Git is doing a merge, it will directly compare the merge base to the two branch tips to get the changesets, rather than summing together all the intermediate changesets. The results differ in difficult-rename cases...

Comment: @torek When you say, "it's actually a snapshot", what is it a snapshot of? My understanding is that a commit only records the changes, not a snapshot of the entire project. Is that not a correct way to see it?

Comment: It's a snapshot of all the files that were in the index at the time you ran `git commit`. These files are compressed, but not deltas. Each checkout populates the index with the snapshot you've checked out. Using `git add` copies a file from the work-tree into the index, compressing as it goes and overwriting the one that *was* in the index, or creating a new file if that's a new filename, and `git rm` *removes* the file from the index (and the work-tree in the process). So the index is always ready-to-go, which makes `git commit` fast.

Comment: For each version of each file, you wind up with a *blob object* in the repository (the file contents, stripped of the file's name). These blob objects are eventually *packed* into "pack files", and those *do* use delta-compression, but at a level invisible to the object abstraction. This means that commit and tree objects can get delta-compressed too. At the higher level, Git just asks for an object by its hash ID. If that's in `.git/objects/` as an unpacked object, Git gets that; if it's in a pack file, deltified, Git has to un-deltify that first.

Comment: @torek So if I understand correctly, the delta-compression only stores the changes between a commit and its parent, but git is implemented in such a way that it constructs the working directory directly rather than replaying each commit on top of each other as I imply in my answer here. Is that right?

Comment: Ah, no: the delta-compression pass, which happens later, doesn't use commit parent/child relationships. Instead, Git strings together, into object chains, various "likely to match" objects (based on object data sizes and some smuggled-in-from-tree-object file names). But this typically happens *much* later, long after committing and merging.

Comment: Note that `git push` and `git fetch` do their own separate delta-compression of objects into a so-called *thin pack* that lacks objects; the other side "fattens" the thin pack by filling in the missing objects, which means the two Gits wind up with asymmetric packs. Eventually `git gc` (which is the thing that builds normal packs normally) runs and rearranges everything by repacking the existing redundant packs into better packs. Again, this is all invisible from the object database: you just have a hash ID (such as a commit hash ID), and use that as a key to get the object data.

Comment: @code-apprentice, thanks for your answer especially highlighting its the CHANGES between to branches that are chosen for merge. I went on to read the link about a Git commit, but still have one question. How does git know if its a New file or a changed file if I simply Rename the file in Branch3 (my example). That file has been deleted in Branch 1 and when I try to merge Branch3 into Branch1, will git detect that 'hey that was a file Branch1's author had deleted and not a new file despite it having a new SHA1 (which I guess will generate a new SHA1).